# NSXMLParser - modify the elements in iPhone

Tags: html, objective-c, nsxmlparser

I have an HTML string that I need to modify its elements.

I looked into `NSXMLParser`, but didn't see any method to modify the elements while reading them.

I don't like the solution of creating a `NSMutableString` and adding strings to it.

Is there a way to read HTML string and modify its element in an elegant way?

e.g.,

```
<div style="color:grey"></div>
```

will be

```
<div style="color:black"></div>
```

Unfortunately I saw that one cannot use `NSXMLDocument` in an iPhone app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the github project KissXML which is a 'clone of NSXML library and works the same. 
https://github.com/robbiehanson/KissXML

---

shameless self-advert: my fork of it works way **better with html** that's not real xml
https://github.com/Daij-Djan/KissXML

Comment: it is implemented ontop of libxml2 like NSXMLParser but it allocates a lot more objects and obviously the memory usage is MUCH higher because the whole tree is loaded... but for 'normal ebpages' thats not a problem on today's device :) and it IS convenient :D

Comment: If I would only parse the HTML and concat it to String would it consume less memory?

Comment: if you parse it with NSXMLParser and just concat to a NSMutableString buffer, it would use less memory but I would not go there right away because it will be much more work and might not be necessary. KissXML might be performant enough for the task. (likely IMO)

Comment: Well - after spending a day or more with it - how do I parse the elements recursively? I may have more than one levels of div with font-size!

Comment: a SAX parser is by default not recursive... I used to built my own data model around it and change the delegate depending on where I am:

Comment: e.g. on <bookstore> start, create a bookstore object and make it delegate, on <book> start make a book and name it delegate. ob book end go back to the bookstore as the delegate, on bookstore end go back to original delegate

Comment: Your fork doesn't work well with HTML. For instance, If the tags are not closed, like <img> it wouldn't parse. See my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14111154/close-all-html-tags-not-only-img and the comments about chatting with you about it. What do you suggest?

Comment: I said .. better :D of course there are no guarantees. make sure you pass options:NSXMLDocumentTidyHTML