# Close all HTML tags (not only IMG)

Tags: html, regex

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2433809/close-all-html-unclosed-img-tags/2434110) question and answer regarding closing img tags.

However, what if I want to close also other tags like link?

I tried to write

```
(<img|link[^>]+)(?<!/)>
```

But it wouldn't work

What is wrong?

Example:

```
<link href="myhref">
<img src="mysrc">
```

but not

```
<link href="myhref"/>
<img src="mysrc"/>
```

Comment: You are using the wrong technology for [working with HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1583).

Comment: Show us the code and example input.

Comment: @Oded I wish it could be true. I am working in objective-c with a library of KissXML that wouldn't parse unclosed HTMLs..

Comment: @Odelya - It is an XML library, not an HTML library. Use the right tool... Unclosed entities are illegal in XML, but some are legal in HTML.

Comment: @Oded I know, but I need a library to READ and WRITE HTML at the same time. And this is the only one that I found. See my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14085042/nsxmlparser-modify-the-elements-in-iphone

Comment: Turning HTML into valid XML isn't as simple as just closing some tags.

Comment: Looks like the accepted answer has a fork that should work for you. If it doesn't, have a word with the author - he might be able to extend the fork for your use.

Comment: @Daij-Djan - That's what I read. But from this question it doesn't appear to parse valid HTML with unclosed elements. Is that the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to limit the scope of your alternation. Otherwise the `<` will only be matched if the left part of the alternation matches, and `[^>]+` will only be matched if the right part does.

```
(<(?:img|link)[^>]+)(?<!/)>
```

should fix this problem. `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group, i. e., just used for grouping, not for capturing. The replace operation (with `\1/>`) remains the same.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but how can I use this in c#? I'm trying to do this with Regex.Replace() but I don't know how... 
            `text = Regex.Replace(text, @"<img[^>]*>", "(<(?:img|link)[^>]+)(?<!/)>");`

Answer (score 1):

You Need to use an HTML parser or libxml2 based parser. There is a **libxml2 wrapper in objective-c called [*hpple*](https://github.com/topfunky/hpple)**. *hpple* can parse messy HTML without any problem.

Comment: I know. My problem was that I also need to read and write. And hpple provides only read. I am using KissXML instead

Comment: KissXML should be able to ... options:NSXMLDocumentTidyHTML

Comment: I tried. I doesn't help. I initialize the document like this:DDXMLDocument *theDocument = [[DDXMLDocument alloc] initWithXMLString:content options:1 error:&error];

Comment: KissXML just wraps libxml2 as well and tries it with html mode and also bundles CTidy

Answer (score 1):

KissXML should be able to parse it ... 
it wraps libxml2 in xml mode BUT falls back to html mode!

- when you pass options:NSXMLDocumentTidyHTML it calls CTidy too

---

it WORKS fine :D really (as I keep saying ;))

```
- (void)processNode:(DDXMLNode*)node {
if(node.kind==DDXMLElementKind) {
    NSLog(@"%@", node.name);
    for (id child in node.children) {
        [self processNode:child];
    }
}
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
id sample = @"<link href=\"myhref\"><img src=\"mysrc\">";
id data = [sample dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
DDXMLDocument *doc = [[DDXMLDocument alloc] initWithData:data options:DDXMLDocumentTidyHTML error:nil];
[self processNode:doc.rootElement];
}
```

Comment: Will this help treating entity reference like &nsbp?

Comment: I tried. But this <img src="mysrc"> makes it fall. I initialize the document like this:DDXMLDocument *theDocument = [[DDXMLDocument alloc] initWithXMLString:content options:1 error:&error]; . Please note that I develop for iphone

Comment: I know, else the whole thing wouldnt be needed... it works fine with bad html

Comment: I just tried your code and get the following in error: Domain=DDXMLErrorDomain Code=1 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (DDXMLErrorDomain error 1.)" Please note that I put 1 in options and not DDXMLDocumentTidyHTML

Comment: that code works in multiple projects I dont know about... seems wrong

Comment: What do you suggest for me to check? Is there a way to get a more specific error message? I get it from error description

Comment: dont pass one .. if that doesnt help maybe debug it and step through!?

Comment: I am trying your advice to debug it. However on this line xmlDocPtr doc = xmlParseMemory([data bytes], [data length]); in DDXMLDocument it returns an error. I couldn't debug deeper. What could be the problem?

Comment: doc is null. I see here: xmlDocPtr doc = xmlParseMemory([data bytes], [data length]);
 if (doc == NULL)
 {
  if (error) *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"DDXMLErrorDomain" code:1 userInfo:nil];
  
  return nil;
 }